# Update authorization header in flux WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I'm trying to create a resilient sse (server sent event) client in reactive programming.
The sse endpoint is authenticated, therefore I have to add an authorization header to each request.

The authorization token expires after 1 hour.

Below is a snippet of my code

```
        webClient.get()
                .uri("/events")
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(authService.getIdToken()))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(ServerSideEvent.class)
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(TIMEOUT))
                .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(Long.MAX_VALUE, Duration.ofSeconds(RETRY_DELAY)))
                .subscribe(
                        content -> {
                            handleEvent(content);
                        },
                        error -> logger.error("Error receiving SSE: {}", error),
                        () -> logger.info("Completed!!!"));
```

If after 1 hour the connection is lost for any reason, this code stops working because the token is expired.

How can I refresh the token into the retry logic or in some other way?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use webclient filter.

A filter can intercept and modify client request and response.
Example:

```java
WebClient.builder().filter((request, next) -> {
    ClientRequest newReuqest = ClientRequest.from(request)
            .header("Authorization", "YOUR_TOKEN")
            .build();

    return next.exchange(newRequest);
}).build();
```

UPDATE:

Sorry, Not read your question clearly. Try this:

Assume that server return 401 code when token expired.

```java
WebClient.builder().filter((request, next) -> {
    final Mono<ClientResponse> response = next.exchange(request);
    return response.filter(clientResponse -> clientResponse.statusCode() != HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
            // handle 401 Unauthorized (token expired)
            .switchIfEmpty(next.exchange(ClientRequest.from(request)
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBearerAuth(getNewToken()))
                    .build()));
}).build();
```

Or you can cache your token (e.g. Save to redis and set TTL in one hour), when the token is empty from redis, get new one then save to redis again.

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the task of token refresh? Isn't this just setting the auth header that's already set by `httpHeaders.setBearerAuth()` in the OP?

Comment: @Elva clientResponse.statusCode() != HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED is always returning either true or false, why did you put . switchIfEmpty?

Comment: @Pep If the expression is false (response code is 401), then the mono result will be filtered, and `switchIfEmpty` will be executed. See [Mono.filter](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)